# Easiest way to collect data recorded using a chrome extension (with user consent)

Tags: database, google-chrome-extension, webserver, user-data

**What is the easiest method of getting data from many users' chrome extensions to me?**

**Details:**
I have developed chrome extension that records data from many users (with their explicit consent - the point of the project is data collection). I need to somehow collect this user data centrally, but not sure the easiest way to go about this.

Having done a bit of research, it seems like a way to do this is to set up a webserver, which in turn connects to a database.

However, while I've messed around with a few different languages for different mini-projects, I am a pretty novice programmer (and have never touched anything backend - servers and databases etc), so have little understanding of the size of that challenge.

My question is therefore:

1. What is the path of least resistance for the above method (webserver + database)
2. (Better still) is there an easier way of doing this. Could I hack together some kind of "it sends the data in an email to me" or alternative bad-practise-but-at-least-it-works kind of method for getting the data from many users chrome extensions to me.

**Other background** - don't know how important this is:

- The user data is effectively 15x fields with c 100 entries for
  each user.
- There are likely to be c100-200 users max.
- A one- off / very infrequent collection of the data is fine (it wont change much day to day, for example)

If there's any detail I've missed off that is important, please do comment and I'll add. I considered sharing some code from my project, but since the question is a bit more "conceptual" I thought it wouldn't be that helpful.

Comment: I think [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) suits your needs. It is possible to config it with zero-server code.

Comment: This looks very helpful. It also looks like they have an example to use for chrome extensions here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

Comment: Try using Firebase as a database. You can use this [chrome extension](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension) and [tutorial](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2018/04/05/building-a-chrome-extension-using-firebase-real-time-database/) to guide you in using Firebase and chrome extension. Also you will need to be familiar about [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks both - if you post below I will accept as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [google firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/).

This turned out to be super easy to implement, and is relatively well documented also.

Thanks the the comments above